# Getting input value from from to codeigniter controller and initializing in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This has been a previously asked question but I need serious help in this so re posting it from a friend. I have a input field here.

```
<form  action="index.php/money/save_userinput" method="post" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;">

            <a  type="submit" style="background-color:#fff; color:#66cccc;" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/money/firstpage">GetCash</a> 
  </form>
```

Then I try to get this value from the input field into the controller which is not receiving any values while debugging. This is the function.

```
public function save_userinput(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $form_data = $this->input->post();
    }
```

and what I am trying to do now is using the value from the first page and get those values in a knockout js slider in a completely different page.
Here is the slider code.

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id="ex2Slider" type="text" data-bind="sliderValue: {value: amount, min:0, max: 5000, step: 1, tooltip: 'always', formatter:formatter2}"
            style="display: none;">
```

And I have a knockout js page which has the function,

```
self.amount = ko.observable(2500);
        self.formatter1 = function(amount) {
          return amount + ' kk';
        }
```

I need to put that value I get from the controller into the observable but I am not sure how to do it at all , I tried different methods but non are working. I was thinking of calling the function with Ajax but I am not sure which one should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're posting from a form, it's better to use php and echo it like this and you cannot use `<a>` tags, needs to be `<input>` or else it won't be able to submit and you need to have a name in your input field.

```
<?php echo form_open('money/save_userinput');  ?>
    <input  type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
    <input type="submit" value="invest"/>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

In your code igniter controller create a data array to get the variables like this.

```
public function invest_first_page(){
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $userProvidedAmount = $this->input->post("writtenamount");
        $data =  array(
        'userProvidedAmount' => $userProvidedAmount
         );
        $this->load->view("yoursecondpage", $data);
        }
```

And in your second page where you have the input slider write your code like this.

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id="ex2Slider" type="text"
 data-bind="sliderValue: {value: amount, min:0, max: 5000, step: 1, tooltip: 'always', formatter:formatter2}"
 style="display: none;">
<span id="Amount" data-value="<?php echo $userProvidedAmount ; ?>"</span>
```

And finally now in your knockout js file which you have, write it like this.

```
self.amount = ko.observable($('#Amount').data('value'));
        self.formatter1 = function(amount) {
          return amount + ' kk';
        }
```

Hopefully this will do the trick.